# How to combine two loops

Tags: r

In a tutorial on for() Loops came across the following exercise:

Exercise 4.4. Write a function to perform matrix-vector multiplication. It should take a matrix A and a vector b as arguments, and return the vector Ab. Use two loops to do this, rather than %*% or any vectorization.

Lets say I use a specific matrix A(dim:3,4) and vector b(length(3)).

```
> # Ex 4.4
> out<-c(1,1,1)
> Ab<-function(A,b) {
+   for(i in 1:dim(A)[1]) {
+     
+       out[i]=sum(A[i,]*b)
+   }
+     out
+ }
> a = c(1,1,1)
> A
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    4    7
[2,]    2    5    8
[3,]    3    6   10
> a
[1] 1 1 1
> Ab(A,a)
[1] 12 15 19
```

This works for a very specific case, i.e. matrix with 3 rows  and vector of length 3, but leaves much to be desired, i don't know what a good solution to this exercise would be but the question says 'use two loops'.  Suggestions will be much appreciated.
thx

Comment: IMO, you shouldn't be using any tutorial that encourages `for()` loops when a  vectorized method is available.

Comment: Just realized once out is initialized (out=1) I can multiple any matrix A with vector b, as long as the they are compatible. Now i feel a little better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are hiding the inner loop with `A[i,]*b` which is doing vectorized multiplication (ie. a hidden loop).  So, if you expand that out explicitly you will have the two required loops.

```
Ab<-function(A,b) {
    if (dim(A)[2] != NROW(b)) stop("wrong dimensions")
    out <- matrix(, nrow(A), 1)
    for(i in 1:dim(A)[1]) {
        s <- 0
        for (j in 1:dim(A)[2]) s <- s + A[i,j] * b[j]
        out[i] <- s
    }
    out
}
```